Old English Light Wood Stain Mistake
I messed up while trying to fix some big scratches in our hardwood floors and feel really bad about it. I picked up some Old English Light Wood stain to cover the scratches, but it turned out way too dark and now it sticks out even more. Is there any way to fix this without having to sand it down?
I definitely should've tested a small area first—I didn’t think it through...
Here are some pictures :(
https://postimg.cc/WhCB9B6J
https://postimg.cc/06qLv74k

Is it real hardwood or laminate/LVP flooring?

I don't think there is any way to remove the stain from the wood that wouldn't cause more damage than sanding it would.

It's real hardwood :( . Appreciate the confirmation. I will try my best not to aggravate it further!
